# Can I have struct that can be constructed both from a slice and from an owning buffer?

Tags: rust

I'll try to be as clear as possible. Let's suppose I have:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    buffer: &'a [u8],
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn create_builder() -> FooBuilder {
        FooBuilder::new()
    }

    fn from_slice(slice: &[u8]) -> Foo {
        Foo { buffer: slice }
    }
}

struct FooBuilder {
    in_progress_buffer: Vec<u8>,
}

impl FooBuilder {
    fn new() -> FooBuilder {
        FooBuilder { in_progress_buffer: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, item: u8) {
        self.in_progress_buffer.push(item);
    }

    fn build_foo(self) -> Foo {
        Foo { buffer: self.in_progress_buffer }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // Option1: Gradually construct Foo from FooBuilder
    let mut foo_builder = FooBuilder::new();
    foo_builder.push(7);
    let foo = foo_builder.build_foo();

    // Option2: Construct Foo from a slice
    let v = vec![7];
    let foo2 = Foo::from_slice(&v);
}
```

This gives a compilation error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:28:27
   |
28 |     fn build_foo(self) -> Foo {
   |                           ^^^ expected lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
   = help: consider giving it a 'static lifetime
```

Is this pattern possible? How can I fix the compilation error?
I'm not sure what lifetime specifier to give since in the `FooBuilder` version, the `FooBuilder` owns the buffer, and I don't want to force `Foo` users to keep the `FooBuilder` in scope for the entire duration `Foo` is used

Comment: It seems at first glance that you could use a [`CoW`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html). :)

Comment: Why Foo does not own the buffer?

Comment: @Boiethios I'd like to allow Foo to be de-serialized from a slice. Foo provides methods that inspect the slice (e.g. how many items in the buffer are set to 42) but it never mutates the buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::borrow::Cow`; as the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) state:

> it can enclose and provide immutable access to borrowed data, and clone the data lazily when mutation or ownership is required

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct Foo<'a> {
    buffer: Cow<'a, [u8]>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn create_builder() -> FooBuilder {
        FooBuilder::new()
    }

    fn from_slice(slice: &[u8]) -> Foo {
        Foo { buffer: slice.into() } // note .into()
    }
}

struct FooBuilder {
    in_progress_buffer: Vec<u8>,
}

impl<'a> FooBuilder {
    fn new() -> FooBuilder {
        FooBuilder { in_progress_buffer: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, item: u8) {
        self.in_progress_buffer.push(item);
    }

    fn build_foo(self) -> Foo<'a> {
            Foo { buffer: self.in_progress_buffer.into() } // note .into()
    }
}
```

In addition, you will need to make `foo_builder` mutable in order to be able to perform `push` on it.